# Zurb Foundation 6 Column Center doesn't work

Tags: css, zurb-foundation-6

I try to center a column in a row in **Zurb Foundation 6**.

I'm using the following default classes: `small-6 small-centered columns`, but in ChromeDevTool, I noticed that the float of `.columns:last-child:not(:first-child)` overwrites the float of `.small-centered.columns`.

When I insert multiple columns everything works correctly, except the last column.
Is it a Foundation's bug?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/giotramu/bLx7Lgje/3/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 2):

No this is not a bug in Foundation, this is the intended behavior. If you look at http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#incomplete-rows it describes why they do this.

If you want to override this behavior it's quite easy. Just add this css to override the float.

```
.columns:last-child:not(:first-child) {
  float:none;
}
```

Comment: That's not intended behavior if you're centering the columns. Scroll down to centering section of the docs to see.  @Giovanni's first example in thr fiddle should be centered.

Comment: @ColinMarshall - That's because Giovanni had another element inside the `row`. See https://jsfiddle.net/ue6tp76w/ for an example.

Comment: Ahh i see the h6 is causing this behavior. Good find.